# Android Limit EditText to Integer input only

Tags: java, android

I am trying to apply some kind of verification to an edittext. A user should only be able to enter integers between 1 and 60. I am wondering whether I should let them type whatever they like and when they focus off of the edittext check the contents and if it is out of bounds change the value to a default, say 0.

Or is there a way to limit the keyboard to only allow integers?

UPDATE:
I am doing everything programmatically. So far I have been able to limit to only numeric input and have a maximum of 2 characters by implementing the following. I am still struggling to limit only values between 0 and 60 though.

```
    editText.setInputType( InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER );
    InputFilter[] FilterArray = new InputFilter[1];
    FilterArray[0] = new InputFilter.LengthFilter(2);
    editText.setFilters(FilterArray);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of `android.text.method.KeyListener` to replace the current input with whatever you like.

Since you dont have to change all the keys you can use `addTextChangedListener(TextWatcher watcher)` method like this:

```
EditText editT = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.your_id);
editT.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

});
```

Make use of it to check whether your input is beyond what you are looking and you can even neglect the keys by checking on that loop.

**In XML:**

- If you are using numbers only use `android:inputType="number"`.
- To limit the no of digits to 2 include `android:maxLength="2"`.

Answer (score 1):

If you limit to numbers only, you could use the

```
EditText.addTextChangedListener
```

to get the value inputed and verify it's not over 60

You can easily allow only numbers by adding
`android:numeric="integer"`
to the `EditText` in the layout xml file

Though it is worth mentioning that `android:numeric="integer"` is now deprecated

Comment: `android:numeric="integer"` is very fine and handy, but sadly it's deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

I've got it! I scoured the internet forever, and put a few things together to get it to work.
Basically what it does is runs a parallel process that will be constantly running while the user has their focus on the particular edittext box. It will set a filter so that the user can only enter 0-5 in the first integer slot, but will be allowed to enter 0-9 for the second. This will obviously give 0-59 instead of 1-60, but that's what you want for seconds anyways.
This code goes before the onCreate method, inside of your class:

```
final InputFilter filter = new InputFilter() 
{
    public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end,
                Spanned dest, int dstart, int dent)
    {
        for (int i = start; i < end; i++)
        {
            if ((source.charAt(start) == "6".charAt(0)) || (source.charAt(start) == "7".charAt(0)) || (source.charAt(start) == "8".charAt(0))
                    || (source.charAt(start) == "9".charAt(0)) || (!Character.isDefined(source.charAt(i))) )                            
            {
                return "";
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
 };

private class FilterCheckerTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
{       
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) 
    {           
        while(true)
        {               
            if (<EditText>.getText().toString().isEmpty())
            {
                Log.e("empty","empty");                 
                <EditText>.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{filter, new InputFilter.LengthFilter(2)});              
            }
            else if (<EditText>.getText().toString().charAt(0) >= "6".charAt(0))
            {
                Log.e("front num bad","greater than 5");
                <EditText>.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{filter, new InputFilter.LengthFilter(2)});
            }
            else 
            {
                Log.e("unfiltered", "unfiltered");
                <EditText>.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{new InputFilter.LengthFilter(2)});      
            }
            if (kicker)
            {
                return null;
            }
        }           
    }       
}
```

Then, within the `onCreate` method:

```
    Time_sec.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() 
    {
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus)
        {
            new FilterCheckerTask().execute();
            if(!hasFocus)
                    {kicker = !hasFocus;}                               

        }
    });
```

As I said in the first part, this will make it so the user can only input numbers between 00 and 59 in your edittext box. I know it may look a little sloppy, and it can probably be cleaned up a bit in some of the if statements, but as far as I can tell it works absolutely perfectly, and doesn't seem to slow the system at all. Hope this helps you, and if not, the future googlers.

Comment: What'd be if I want to put just 7 there?